# C++ feature, like std::set, which allows duplicates

Tags: c++, list, c++11, std-pair, stdset

I have an `std::set`, which stores `std::pair`s of two integers. The `std::set` is also sorted, by allowing me to pass a helping class. However, I have written many lines of code so far and now, at the last tests, "they" told me something, that actually means that I need to allow possible duplicates in the `std::set`. Of course this isn't done with `std::set`. Any alternative that will not make me change the whole-big project?

In short, I use the `std::set` as an ordered list with data an `std::pair` of two ints.

Comment: So.. you want a [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) ?

Comment: Wow, probably yes. I will check!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `std::multiset`. That should work for what you are describing.

Answer (score 7):

[std::multiset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/begin/) is the answer, as suggested by WhozCraig.